# Passing Complex object from View to Controller: one object is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel, parameter-passing

I'm passing a complex object as a `Model` to the `View` as

[image]

but when I get the Model back from the View, one particular object comes always `null` while other complex types are normally passed through

[image]

my View is the default `Edit` Strongly Typed View

[image]

> **What am I missing**?

The **ModelState** Error says

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Julekalender.Database.CalendarInfo' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.

**Why don't** I get the same for the other types? **How is** it automatically converted?

---

I have added 3 fields (as the T4 template does not append this types) but I still get null when `POST`ing

The green boxed below is the field

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Calendar.Guid)%>
</div>
```

[image]

---

Even renaming the Action to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult General2(GeneralInfo model)
```

gives the same error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that when you use this wizard there are input fields generated in the view for **each** property of the Calendar object so that when you post the form they will be sent to the controller action. I am not sure this is the case (haven't verified if the wizard does it for complex objects, I've never used this wizard).

In the resulting HTML you should have:

```
<input type="text" name="Calendar.Prop1" value="prop1 value" />
<input type="text" name="Calendar.Prop2" value="prop2 value" />
... and so on for each property you expect to get back in the post action
... of course those could be hidden fields if you don't want them to be editable
```

---

UPDATE:

The problem comes from the fact that you have a string variable called `calendar` in your action method and an object which has a property called `Calendar` which is confusing. Try renaming it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult General2(string calendarModel, GeneralInfo model)
```

Also don't forget to rename it in your view.

Comment: I did it for just 3 fields http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-11-07_1458.png but I still don't get the object, do I need to have all fields?

Comment: No, a single fields is enough to instantiate the object. Ahhhh I see now. Rename this `calendar` variable in your action method as it is confusing with the `Calendar` property.

Comment: but that is my route `"{calendar}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` so I can pass a calendar name (so I know what calendar belongs all actions to) like `http://domain/demo/Content/General2` I know that it requested the General Content for Calendar named `demo`.

Comment: Well that's the problem. You can only have one calendar :-) As an alternative rename the Calendar property in the GeneralInfo class.

Comment: but... even without it, I get the same :( http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-11-07_1508.png

Comment: Have you removed the `<input name="calendar" type="text" />` from your view?

Comment: there is no such thing, as `string calendar` comes from the route, not an input: http://pastebin.com/rcf1UDvT

Comment: Well then remove it from the route. You cannot bind string (which comes from your route) to a complex CalendarInfo object.

Comment: dang... I was expecting that `calendar` and `Calendar` would be differentiated, but no... I changed my route from  `calendar` to `calurl` and works like a charm now. Thank you for your time on this!